# How to update a paper-dropdown-menu after I changed the items?

Tags: polymer-2.x, paper-elements

I use a paper-dropdown-menu with Polymer 2.0 to provide a selection. The elements themselves can change due to some outer influence. When that happens, the shown element does not update.

An example:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+:master/webcomponents+:master/shadycss+webcomponents+:master/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-button/paper-button.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-item/paper-item.html">
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer-element.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-listbox/paper-listbox.html">
</head>
<body>


<dom-module id="my-element">

  <template>
    <paper-dropdown-menu label="Dinosaurs">
      <paper-listbox slot="dropdown-content" selected="0">
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[_dinosaurs]]">
          <paper-item>[[item]]</paper-item>
        </template>
      </paper-listbox>
    </paper-dropdown-menu>
    <paper-button on-tap="changeList">Change List</paper-button>
  </template>


  <script>
      HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
          class MyElement extends Polymer.Element {
              static get is() { return 'my-element'; }
              static get properties() {
                  return {
                      _dinosaurs: {
                          type: Array,
                          value: ['Initial entry :D No dinosaurs here :(']
                      }
                  };
              }

              constructor() {
                  super();
                  this.prop = 'my-element'
              }

              changeList() {
                  if (this._dinosaurs.length < 3) {
                      this.set('_dinosaurs', ['allosaurus', 'brontosaurus', 'carcharodontosaurus', 'diplodocus']);
                  }
                  else {
                      this.set('_dinosaurs', ['There is only T-Rex!']);
                  }
              }
          }
          customElements.define(MyElement.is, MyElement);
      });

  </script>

</dom-module>

<my-element></my-element>

</body>
</html>
```

The paper-listbox is initially filled with one element that is initially selected. When the button "Change List" is pressed, the content of the paper-listbox changes, including the element at position 0, i.e., the current selection. However, the shown text remains the same. How can I update the shown element when the elements of the listbox are changed?

Answer (score 0):

See the usage of `attr-for-selected`, below.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+:master/webcomponents+:master/shadycss+webcomponents+:master/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-button/paper-button.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-item/paper-item.html">
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer-element.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-listbox/paper-listbox.html">
</head>
<body>


<dom-module id="my-element">

  <template>
    <paper-dropdown-menu label="Dinosaurs">
      <paper-listbox slot="dropdown-content" attr-for-selected="item-name">
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[_dinosaurs]]">
          <paper-item item-name="[[item]]">[[item]]</paper-item>
        </template>
      </paper-listbox>
    </paper-dropdown-menu>
    <paper-button on-tap="changeList">Change List</paper-button>
  </template>


  <script>
      HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
          class MyElement extends Polymer.Element {
              static get is() { return 'my-element'; }
              static get properties() {
                  return {
                      _dinosaurs: {
                          type: Array,
                          value: ['Initial entry :D No dinosaurs here :(']
                      }
                  };
              }

              constructor() {
                  super();
                  this.prop = 'my-element'
              }

              changeList() {
                  if (this._dinosaurs.length < 3) {
                      this.set('_dinosaurs', ['allosaurus', 'brontosaurus', 'carcharodontosaurus', 'diplodocus']);
                  }
                  else {
                      this.set('_dinosaurs', ['There is only T-Rex!']);
                  }
              }
          }
          customElements.define(MyElement.is, MyElement);
      });

  </script>

</dom-module>

<my-element></my-element>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Unfortunately, that doesn't solve my problem. With attr-for-selected the names of the item would be used as index values as well, if I understand the function correctly. However, I want to keep the old index. So, in my example, if the 'Initial entry ...' is shown and I click 'Change List', I'd like the shown selection to change to 'allosaurus' as this is the new item with index 0. With your method, the dropdown just looses its previous value if it doesn't exist any more.